# Catch on drop event in document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, jslink, drag-and-drop

I am trying to write a JSLink file that hooks to the event "ondrop" (or whatever it is called) from a document library. The reason behind this is, we want a jquery dialog to open when someone drags a document into the document library where you have to enter some meta information.

Is this possible? If yes is there any documentation available on this?
I found that especially javascript and JSLink stuff is very poorly documented on MSDN.
Also all tutorials about JSLink I could find only explain how to use it to change the rendering of a field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so after hours and days of digging thorugh thousends of lines of sharpeoint javascript code I finally managed to hook into the document drop event.

## Setting JSLink

First you have to assign a Javascript file as JSLink to the document library view.

## Javascript code

In that javascript file I then used the following code

```
// Load base script file
if (!document.Share2013BaseScriptFileIncluded) {
    document.write("<script src='/_layouts/15/Eis.Share2013.Base/Scripts/Eis.Share2013.Base.js'" + "></script>");
    document.Share2013BaseScriptFileIncluded = true;
}

// Register namespace
Type.registerNamespace("Eis.Share2013.CatchDrop");

setTimeout(function () {

    Eis.Share2013.EnsureJQueryLoaded(function () {

        window.eisCatchDropInterval = setInterval(function () {
            if ($("#ms-dnd-dropbox").length > 0) {

                $("#ms-dnd-dropbox")[0].removeEventListener("drop", DropBoxDrop, false);
                $("#ms-dnd-dropbox")[0].removeEventListener("drop", Eis.Share2013.CatchDrop.Catch, false);
                $("#ms-dnd-dropbox")[0].addEventListener("drop", Eis.Share2013.CatchDrop.Catch, false);

            }
        }, 10);
    });
}, 100);

Eis.Share2013.CatchDrop.Catch = function (event) {
    console.log("Drop event catched by EIS");
    cancelDefault(event);
    HideDropBox();
    if (!UserHasPermission()) {
        return false;
    }
    var dt = event.dataTransfer;
    var droppedFiles = dt.files;

    if (!fIsNullOrUndefined(droppedFiles) && droppedFiles.length > 0) {
        g_currentControl.status = ControlStatus.DROPPED;
        PrepareFileList(droppedFiles);
        var files = g_currentControl.files;

        if (!fIsNullOrUndefined(files)) {
            StartTask(files);
        }
    }
    else {
        ShowErrorDialogCore(Strings.STS.L_DragDropNotWorkingErrorTitle, Strings.STS.L_DragDropInvalidFile, null);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The base file I included here loads jquery and the function `Eis.Share2013.EnsureJQueryLoaded` makes sure that for the code inside the callback function jQuery is loaded.

I had to create an interval function, that removes the default events on the dropbox and attach my event. This is because the droppox gets created and setup everytime you drag a new item into the page. This was the only way I could find to make sure that my event is registered all the time.

My custom event is simply the copied code from the original sharepoint event (except for the  `console.log`). You can now add your custom logic into the `Eis.Share2013.EnsureJQueryLoaded` function.

Comment: Hi RononDex, 
Thanks for your amazing workaround.
It works absolutely perfect. I am facing an issue when I have more than 1 listview web parts in a page then above script is only applies on first web part. Do you know how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Long time reader first time poster. For an entirely client side solution I have found this to be effective with Document Libraries in SharePoint 2013.

The sleep serves to make sure the ms-dnd-dropbox exists before adding the event listener to it. On older, slow clients removing this has been known to cause an error, 50ms has been working as a reasonable time long enough for the computer but to fast for a human to release (at least it hasn't happened yet).

None to quick with the JS - if someone has a better way to deal with this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Need to wait for page to load (else can error)
    $("#WebPartWPQ2")[0].addEventListener("dragleave",function() {
        //sleep real quick
        setTimeout(function() {
            //Zzzzz
        },50);  

        //Need to wait for the event to occur before the div exists (else errors)
        $("#ms-dnd-dropbox")[0].addEventListener("drop",function() {
            console.log("Hey boss!");
        });
    });
});
```