# Open 'Edit Form' Modal Box when a Document is Dragged into Library WP

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, document-library

I would like to force an 'Edit Form' modal box to open whenever a user drags a document into a Document Library Web Part. I have no idea how to do this -- is it possible?

This worked perfectly for me...

```
(function (_window) {
    var maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc = 10000;
    function replaceUploadProgressFunc() {
        if (typeof _window.UploadProgressFunc != 'undefined') {
            _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc = _window.UploadProgressFunc;
            _window.UploadProgressFunc = Custom_UploadProgressFunc;
            console.log('replaced dialog');
        } else if (maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc > 0) {
            maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc -= 100;
            setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);


    function Custom_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state) {
        _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state);
        var messageType = ProgressMessage.EMPTY;
        switch (state.status) {
            case 1:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.VALIDATION;
                break;
            case 3:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADING;
                break;
            case 4:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADED;
                OpenEditFormForLastItem(state);
                break;
            case 5:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.CANCELLED;
                break;
        }

        function OpenEditFormForLastItem(state) {
            var caml = '';
            caml += "<View>";
            caml += "<Query>";
            caml += "<Where>";

            if (state.files.length > 1) {
                caml += "<In>";
                caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
                caml += "<Values>";
            } else {
                caml += "<Eq>";
                caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
            }

            state.files.forEach(function (file) {
                //only succesfull uploaded files that arent overwrites
                console.log(file);
                if (file.status === 5 /*&& !file.overwrite*/) {
                    caml += "<Value Type='File'>" + file.fileName + "</Value>";
                }
            }, this);

            if (state.files.length > 1) {
                caml += "</Values>";
                caml += "</In>";
            } else {
                caml += "</Eq>";
            }

            caml += "</Where>";
            caml += "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
            caml += "</Query>";
            caml += "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>";
            caml += "<RowLimit>500</RowLimit>";
            caml += "</View>";
            console.log(caml);

            var cntxt = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = cntxt.get_web();
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(window.ctx.ListTitle);
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml(caml);
            var items = list.getItems(query);
            cntxt.load(list, 'DefaultEditFormUrl');
            cntxt.load(items);
            cntxt.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                function openEditForItem() {
                    if (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
                        var id = item.get_id();

                        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                        options.title = "Add File Metadata";
                        options.url = list.get_defaultEditFormUrl() + '?ID=' + id;
                        options.autoSize = true;
                        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = openEditForItem;
                        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                    } else {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
                openEditForItem();
            }, function (error, args) {
                    console.log("failed to get new uploaded items");
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(args);
                });
        }
    }
})(window);
```

Comment: Try implementing this to catch the drop event and open your form in the event handler http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113349/catch-on-drop-event-in-document-library

Comment: How do I add my open form in modal box script?  I'm using this SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage

Comment: You need to open this form only **after document is uploaded**, right?

Comment: Exactly. The Document is dropped into the LVWP on the site Page, and the form opens after it has uploaded

Comment: Did you see this [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata)

Comment: please don't edit the titles to say they are solved, the act of accepting an answer indicates it is solved

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this.

Add Event listener for new element
and then use **SP.UI.ModalDialog** with the id of new file

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
    if (event.target.parentElement.parentElement.id === 'onetidDoclibViewTbl0') {//
        if (!isNaN(event.target.id.split(',')[1])) {

            var dlgOptions = { url: '/Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=' + event.target.id.split(',')[1], autoSize: true, autoSizeStartWidth: 550 };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dlgOptions);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a screenshot from what is actually happening when I drag a document. I copy and pasted the script you'd posted, and it just hangs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It will try to open all the items in modal one by one, so you have to modify the code to stop it.

Comment: But I just wanted it to open the form everytime a document was dropped in...that's it

Comment: @TheJDScott: Did you see this answer - [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata)? This is exactly what you want.